# Can I take more than one picture with the UIImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to offer the user with the possibility of taking more than one picture within the `UIImagePickerController`, just like the Apple Camera App. The behavior of the controller itself mustnot be changed. So, after the user has chosen to use the current photo he has shot, i want the controller to return to the "Take picture" view.

How can I do this? It would be the best if I can "reset" the controller somehow in the delegate methods for `UIImagePickerController`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it myself.

I created a subclass of UIImagePickerController and created a new delegate type which can receive a "didAppear" event. This event is used by my UIImagePickerController subclass to forward the "viewDidAppear" event to the new delegate I created. Et voila ;)!

C YA @ll